# Potentially insecure random numbers on Android 4.3 and older

Tags: java, android

After updating Android SDK, I noticed this new warning in my code:

`Potentially insecure random numbers on Android 4.3 and older. Read https://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/08/some-securerandom-thoughts.html for more info.`

My code for usage is following where `seed` is user typed string:

```
KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES"); // Gives warning
SecureRandom sr = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG", "Crypto");
sr.setSeed(seed);
kgen.init(BLOCKS, sr);
SecretKey skey = kgen.generateKey();
```

So my question is, that is the code still safe to use because of the seed? If not does the code in the link provide fix to use the same code after running `PRNGFixes.apply()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. [PRNG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator)s are insecure because of their algorithms, which produce less-than-cryptographically-secure *sequences* of numbers. The seed only determines where in that insecure sequence you're starting your PRNG.

Comment: Any idea if the code get's fixed if I copy the code in the link and run apply() on start of my app?