# by which i can replace AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding for security concern in android application?

Tags: java, android, security, encryption

In my IDE warning displayed as Potentially insecure random numbers on Android 4.3 and older.

Read [Android Development Blog](https://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/08/some-securerandom-thoughts.html) for more info

how to make it secure?

```
package com.example.encryptographytest;

import java.security.Security;
import java.security.spec.KeySpec;    
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String key = "1234567891234567";
      String data = "example";
     Log.d("CRYPTO-TEST", ""+ decrypt(encrypt(data, key), key));
      Log.d("CRYPTO-TEST", ""+encrypt(data, key));  
    }

    public static String encrypt(String input, String key){
      byte[] crypted = null;
      try{
        SecretKeySpec skey = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), "AES");
          Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
          cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skey);
          crypted = cipher.doFinal(input.getBytes());
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
     return new String(Base64.encode(crypted, Base64.DEFAULT));    

       // return new String(Base64.encodeBase64(crypted));
    }

    public static String decrypt(String input, String key){
        byte[] output = null;
        try{
          SecretKeySpec skey = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), "AES");
          Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
          cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skey);
          output = cipher.doFinal( Base64.decode(input, Base64.DEFAULT));
        }catch(Exception e){
          System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
        return new String(output);
    }     
}
```

Answer (score 4):

First off, Android 4.3 is inherently not secure. There are now multiple exploits including remote ones such as StageFright.

Second, I assume you were talking about [some-securerandom-thoughts.html](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.il/2013/08/some-securerandom-thoughts.html), as your link was dead. It's talking about random number generations, but I don't see that in your code. Instead I see AES encryption, which isn't random at all.

Also, looking at [Potentially insecure random numbers on Android 4.3 and older](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23558886/5276890), this warning may have been related to a previous version of your code, which relied on SecureRandom to initialize the KeyGenerator.

Doing a google search for 'aes not secure' brings up all bunch of results and opinions, but it seems secure enough for most people.

Having said that, doing a google for 'ecb not secure' brings up [Why shouldn't I use ECB encryption?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/20946), which aptly demonstrates why it's not secure. But that's not secure on any platform, not just Android 4.3.

Hope this helps and please clarify if the warning really came from this code snippet or specify the exact line.

Comment: Right, the use of ECB is the obvious problem here.